# python: ParseError('a.h:277 before __int64')

Tags: python

After setting up [csjark](http://csjark.readthedocs.io), I'm trying to test on of my C header files which has following statements:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned long X;
   __int64 Y;
} abc;
```

For the __int64 i'm getting the mention error.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Need to see the context you are using this, it sounds like python is trying to parse the header file.

Comment: If I'm changing `__int64` to `unsigned long` I'm not getting this error. However, this H file is generated by some tool, so I can do nothing on this. Unfortunetly, I can't share the .h file as it is in private network.

Comment: @cdarke - you are right. python is trying to parse the header file